# How can I analyse the association between a categorical variable (binary outcome) and a continous variable especially in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, model, association-measure

I want to analyze the association between a binary variable and a continuous variable in R. But I am not clear about what steps I should follow.

I explored the continuous variable by the histogram and got the result that is normally distributed. Then I tried to use the linear regression model with `lm(y~x, data)`, but the assumptions weren't met by the diagnostic plots. After that, I tried the logistic regression model with `glm( y~x, data, family = binomial)` but got a not significant p-value of the model.  I don't know if the steps I did is correct or not since these two variables should relate to each other, and I don't know how to summarize and interpret my procedure and result.

I was wondering if I was doing right for this analysis. Could anyone show me a direction of any other way I could try?

Comment: y the outcome is binary and x the predictor is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

You do not provide any data so I will use the built-in mtcars data where `am` is the binary variable and `disp` is the continuous variable.

If you just want to "analyze the association between" the variables, some options are

```
 aggregate(mtcars$disp, list(mtcars$am), mean)
  Group.1        x
1       0 290.3789
2       1 143.5308
```

and

```
library(sm) 
sm.density.compare(mtcars$disp, mtcars$am)
```

[image: Density plot]

If you want to *predict* the binary variable,  I would recommend `rpart`

```
library(rpart)
rpart(am ~ disp, data=mtcars)
n= 32 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 32 7.718750 0.4062500  
  2) disp>=163.8 18 1.777778 0.1111111 *
  3) disp< 163.8 14 2.357143 0.7857143 *
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not give up on logistic regression. It might very well be that the log-odds of the binary outcome variable is not linear in the predictor $x$, but then you can try to represent the predictor via *regression splines*.  There are many examples on this site, for instance [How to achieve linear relationship between predictors and logit of outcome?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380721/how-to-achieve-linear-relationship-between-predictors-and-logit-of-outcome)  or  [Are splines overfitting the data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49052/are-splines-overfitting-the-data).

After fitting the model look into some model diagnostics, see [Interpreting residual diagnostic plots for glm models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29271/interpreting-residual-diagnostic-plots-for-glm-models).

If you post [a link to] your data I could have a look.